# JavaScript RegExp - g modifier not working

Tags: javascript, regex, jscript, testcomplete

I have been stuck on this **silly** issue for hours now. I know it seems stupid but I really don't know what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my issue:

```
var objReg = /touch/g;
var str = "abc touch def touch";
var arr = objReg.exec(str);
```

Here I expect the array `arr` to contain 2 elements but it only contains the 1st element even though I made sure to put the `g` modifier.

Can anyone guide me what is to be done here?

Debug: As shown in the image below, the array has just 1 element(index=0)

[image]

Comment: You have to repeat `RegExp.exec` until the returned value is `null`. Alternatively, you can use `str.match(re)`, which returns just the array of matches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the effect you want, you need to do the matching with `String.prototype.match()`:

```
var arr = str.match(objReg);
```

The RegExp `.exec()` function does not behave the same way with regards to the `g` flag. The flag *does* do *something* with `.exec()` but not what `.match()` does.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, sir. This solved my problem :'). Will accept the answer as soon as I am able to

Answer (score 6):

The `g` modifier causes the regex object to maintain state. It tracks the index after the last match. If you wanted to use `.exec()`, you can use a loop, and it will automatically start searching the string at the appropriate point.

```js
var objReg = /touch/g;
var str = "abc touch def touch";
var match = null;
var arr = [];

console.log(objReg.lastIndex);

while ((match = objReg.exec(str))) {
  arr.push(match[0]);
  console.log(objReg.lastIndex);
}

console.log(objReg.lastIndex);

console.log(arr);
```